# Can I use Nutralite Butter in baking Cakes and cookies?

Tags: cooking-myth

I am not getting the right type of unsalted butter. Can I use Nutralite salted butter in my cakes?

Comment: What is the right type of unsalted butter? What kind of cake are you making?

Comment: What is your reason for choosing nutralite vs normal butter or baking margarine?

Comment: In the US, we have "European style butters" and "American style butters" (both unsalted). The European style butters have more fat and less water (and are considerably more expensive). There are some recipes which specifically call for European style butters (see for example, Dominique Ansel's cookbook).

Answer (score 1):

After looking that margarine up:

It is advertised as a margarine made of mostly unsatured fats. An ingredient list is not readily found on their website (red flag ;) ) . They also claim to not hydrogenate their fats, so to make a solid margarine you are either looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesterified_fat (will behave similar to butter when baking) or at some textural tricks that keep oil in a solid block (will likely behave like oil in baking).

If your intention is to cut saturated fats, I would suggest you look up cake recipes that use oil in the first place, and use whatever oil suits your culinary and nutritional taste.

Answer (score 0):

I say you should go for it. In the US, regular household cooks often substitute margarine for butter. Many recipes call for "butter or margarine". Most likely a celebrated chef or food critic would be able to spot the substitution (and be appalled by it), but for most people and most recipes, it works out just fine.

If you are using salted butter instead of unsalted, you should of course leave out any other salt, called out separately, in a cake recipe, but even if that option isn't open (no itemized salt in recipe), your finished cake is very unlikely to be inedible.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote this as I don't think it's good advice. Margarine is made of oil, and sometimes it can be a decent substitute but that depends on the recipe.